# Implementing the Repository/UnitOfWork pattern using Azure.Data.Tables "TableClient"

Tags: c#, repository, azure, unit-of-work

I currently have a generic Azure repository `AzureRepository<TEntity>` store internally a list of table transaction actions like so.

`private readonly IList<TableTransactionAction> tableTransactionActions;`

The generic repository implements CRUD methods like this..

```
public void Delete(TEntity entity)
{
    tableTransactionActions.Add(new TableTransactionAction(TableTransactionActionType.Add, entity));
}

public void Insert(TEntity entity)
{
    tableTransactionActions.Add(new TableTransactionAction(TableTransactionActionType.Add, entity));
}
```

IUnitOfWork abstraction

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    int SaveChanges();        

    Task <int> SaveChangesAsync();

    bool BeginTransaction();

    bool Commit();

    Task <bool> CommitAsync();

    void Rollback();
}
```

#### Question

Would you expose the internal list of TableTransactionActions to the unit of work to perform a commit, or rollback in a batch? How would you properly implement repository/unit of work to perform batched CRUD updates (not read of course)? Properly is subjective of course, however, I am looking for an answer that is well supported and makes a lot of sense in the context of Azure.Data.Tables SDK. Feel free to give direction instead of directly answering the question

I am open to creating more layers of abstractions as well like IDataContext.

Assume that I have a mechanism for retrieving repository instances of any type within the `IUnitOfWork`

Comment: Assuming you are trying to use the SubmitTransactions on TableClient (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient?view=azure-dotnet)...

Unlike Relation DB transactions ... TableClient doesn't have a concept of BeginTransaction, Commit and Rollback.

The TableClient.SubmitTransaction does either the 'commit' or 'rollback' itself.

So, the IUnitOfWork implementation is not applicable here.  The IList<TableTransactionAction> itself kind of acts like a 'unit of work' in this case.

Regards

Athadu

Comment: @Athadu This is true. There is no concept of begin, commit, and rollback in this SDK. A simpler, less abstract design seems best suited as you suggest.